# Android DB: Merging Two Databases Using SQL Dumps

Tags: android, database, merge

I'm currently working on the database part of a project where I have to merge the contents of two databases and I would like to ask you if there exists a simple API method 
within the Android API/SDK itself that dumps me a database to a SQL text file.

Actually I found no hint in the API documentation about such an implementation myself. And I really doubt there is a single line method somewhere buried behind the curtain.

However I've already made a workaround using the sqlite3 shell tools of Android Linux by invoking:

```
String[] cmd = {"/system/bin/sh", "-c", ..., "sqlite3 ..."};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd );
```

Where I have two choices, a) pipe it directly to an output file or b) write the file using BufferedOutputStream.

Nevertheless, most likely due to compatibility issues am I asking you of a more convenient way within the API itself, rather than using the critical shell trick within the App.

I am also pretty much interested in any fast & pretty clues about merging two databases using Android's database methods.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in to the API that will help you. You could query, and write the INSERT statements yourself.  There's a blog entry (http://mgmblog.com/2009/02/06/export-an-android-sqlite-db-to-an-xml-file-on-the-sd-card/) , on building an XML file from the results of your query. A few tweaks, and you coule build your own dump file.

You don't say what kind of merge you need to do, but you might be able to use [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/), by doing something like override the equals method on your model objects to compare the records and/or combine data from certain fields (assuming the schema is the same), without having to write a lot of SQL.

Comment: Thanks nice to know. The merge itself is meant to merge potential user customized data to an updated database in case of an App (and database) update.